# Ruby array name quals next name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have array:

I have database, and records from there.

FOR EXAMPLE (where db = model)

```
db = DB.find(:all)

records = db.name

records.to_a
```

and know, how i can do check (because i have similiar records in DB):

```
if record name == next record name
 puts "yes, smiliar"
else
 puts ":("
end
```

I need to check current array name to next and if equals as i showed above just make puts "yes"

Comment: what does `record = db.name` mean? If DB is a model, then `DB.find(:all)`should return an array which has no method `name`

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment to me.

Answer (score 5):

To compare two elements in array, you may use [each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) method

```
[1,2,2,2,1].each_cons(2) do |a| 
  puts (a.first == a.last) ? "similar" : ":(" 
end

# => :(
# => similar
# => similar
# => :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to the previous record is easier. Maybe you can solve your problem this way:

```
prev = nil
records.each do |record|
    if record.name == prev.name
        puts "similar"
    else
        puts ":("
    end
    prev = record
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order, I'd use group_by:

```
db = DB.find(:all, :select => 'name').collect(&:name)
arr = = Array[db.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v|  k if v.size > 1}]
arr.compact!
```

The `:select => 'name'` part is optional, but helps keep the query small.

This returns a list of names which AREN'T unique